# Undefined index wkt in geofield

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to make Geofield work but encountered the following issue: I installed Geofield 7.x-1.2, and add a new field of type geofield and widget type google map(which is added when I install Geolocation 7.x-1.4) but when I save the content type following error message is showing:

```
Notice: Undefined index: wkt in geofield_compute_values() (line 191 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/geofield/geofield.module).
```

I installed Leaflet to try to display my nodes but when I add new content it is showing the same error as above. How to resolve this issue.

Any insight into this would highly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Without any source code all i can say it that you're proving an array to a function which doesn't have the required/expected indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also face the same issue with Geofield 7.x-1.2 and Geolocation 7.x-1.4. The issue can be solved by installing the other version of geofield module Geofield 7.x-2.0-beta1 (don't use the 7.x-2.x-dev version).